# What is the proper way to deal with 3rd party libraries which is not using latest build tool and target SDK version

Tags: android

As the usage of 3rd party library grown, I do have the following concern.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:24.2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:1.0.2'
    ...
}
```

Time-to-time, I will "upgrade" my project, to use the

- Latest build-tool
- Latest support library
- Latest target SDK version

I found out that this is a good habit to do so, in order to take advantage of new features and bug fixing in Android.

However, not all the 3rd party libraries will use the latest build-tool, support library or SDK.

Previously, when there isn't much 3rd party libraries in my app, I will usually contact the authors of the libraries. Most of them will respond positively by upgrading their projects to use the latest thingy.

However, as the usage of 3rd party libraries grown, I found out this is no longer a viable option.

I was wondering,

1. What is the proper way to deal with 3rd party libraries which is not using latest build tool, latest support library and target SDK version?
2. Is it necessary to ensure 3rd party libraries also using same version of build tool, support library and SDK, as my main app?

Answer (score 0):

Fix or change some features of 3rd parties libraries to your own one , for example if we have library called "3rdLibrary" and it cant deal with my build tools or other thing in that moment I just copy whole class to my package and change the line which gives me an error.If it is big libraries I try to find alternative one.